# Select click event issue in IE7 (Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

As IE 7 does not support the `disabled` attribute, I am using jQuery to add an event handler to the `change` event which checks if there is a `disabled` attribute on the select and setting the css `color` to `grey` on the disabled option.

However, as soon I click on the dropdown its closes my dropdown first then re-draw the new one  with the grey color.

Here is my code:

```
(function($) {

    $('select').change(function() {
        if (this.options[this.selectedIndex].disabled) {
            if (this.options.length == 0) {
                this.selectedIndex = -1;
            } else {
                this.selectedIndex--;
            }
            //$(this).trigger('change');
        }
    });
    $('select').each(function(it) {
        if (this.options[this.selectedIndex].disabled) {
            this.onchange();
        }
    });

    $('select').click(function(e) {
        //e.stopPropagation();
        $(this).find('option[disabled]').css({
            'color': '#cccccc'
        });
    });

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Can you please check the revised question still captures your original problem.

Comment: Is that true in quirks, and standards-compliant, mode? Have you tried the `disabled="disabled"` (XHTML) alternative? (I've not used IE for quite a while, so these may be stupid questions...)

Comment: Thanks for edit yes still its capture my issues

Answer (score 0):

Check out this example I've made for you:
http://jsfiddle.net/auNVE/

It should give you enough information for further development!

Good luck!

---

**Edit**
Update after having more information
http://jsfiddle.net/auNVE/1/

---

**Edit**
Now with `mousedown` instead of `click`
http://jsfiddle.net/auNVE/2/

Comment: Thanks your code is working on static dropdown but my dropdown is dynamically genrated disabled attribute on drop down.

Comment: I am having 5 dropdown . If user select any value from first drop then in other dropdown user can not select the same values in other dropdowns.

Comment: I've modified the script, so it does work with the `click` you had first.

Comment: I am sorry again, yes that is I have already done in my script, Its opening dropdown and close immidiately. on second click its working fine. My Assumption is on first click it re-drawing select list thats why its close the dropdown

Comment: Maybe `mousedown` instead of `click`? See modified answer for link

Comment: My disabled attribute is adding dynamically ... no its not working on mousedown as well... :) my bad luck